# Lucene analyzer for substrings

Tags: lucene, substring, analyzer

I have a database table with about 40,000 records containing code fields, such as
FLEFSU25B-25M
EMG1090-5S

I need to be able to very quickly select all codes that contain a given substring. For example "109" matches EMG1090-5S.

My current approach is to store the codes in Lucene and have Lucene filter by substring - such as *109*
But that is not very efficient if I just store the codes, because than Lucene has to search through all the tokens.

To overcome this, I'm thinking of creating a new analyzer that will split each code into tokens, like this:
    EMG1090-5S
     MG1090-5S
      G1090-5S
       1090-5S
    ...

Then to find all codes with substring 109, I can search on 109* which is much more efficient (I understand Lucene stores tokens alphabetically, just like SQL Server indexes).

Does this make sense?
Does such an analyzer already exist? I'm using .Net/C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A token filter to accomplish this does indeed already exist!  Take a look at [EdgeNGramTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenFilter.html).  An `Analyzer` using it might look something like:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    KeywordTokenizer source = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
    LowercaseFilter filter = new LowercaseFilter(source);
    filter = new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(filter, EdgeNGramTokenFilter.Side.BACK, 2, 50);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```

---

For your consideration, [`WordDelimiterTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) might also prove useful to you.  It has a number of configuartion options, and can be used to separate at punctuation and at transitions from letter to number, etc.  So with it, you could get the from your input:  "EMG1090-5S"

You could get the tokens:

- EMG
- 1090
- 5
- S

Which might work well for your case, but would not be particularly helpful in finding something like: "MG1"